# Simplifying a natural log with a denominator inside

Tags: calculus

Given  $ln(|\frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}7) + \frac{x}7|)$

How come that can be simplified to:
 $ln(|\sqrt{x^2-49}) + x|)$ ?

As explained below:

It's an indefinte integral so $ln(|\frac{\sqrt{x^2-49}}7) + \frac{x}7|)$ becomes

$ln(|\frac{1}7(\sqrt{x^2-49} + x|))$ -> $ln(\frac{1}7) + ln(|\sqrt{x^2-49}) + x|)$

And $ln(\frac{1}7)$ is a constant so it gets absorbed by the constant of integration.

Comment: There is some bracket problem. However, you cannot neither get that result

Comment: So, I'm taking the $$\int{}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-49}}$$ and using both https://www.integral-calculator.com/ and http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321947345-calculus-early-transcendentals-2nd-edition/537/exercises/18/ ( the solution) there's a step where they simplify it by removing that 7 in the denominator.

Comment: It differs for a constant which is $\log 7$. Then if you are integrating, you are not interested in constants

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain that a bit more please? I'm lost.

Comment: You should show the derivation step you have a question about so we don't have to go looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  It is true that $\frac {\sqrt{49-x^2}}7+\frac x7=\frac 17(\sqrt {49-x^2}+x)$ so $\ln|\frac {\sqrt{49-x^2}}7+\frac x7|=\ln|\frac 17(\sqrt {49-x^2}+x)|=\ln7+\ln|(\sqrt {49-x^2}+x)|$.  In your comment you indicate this is the result of an indefinite integal, which comes with an aribtrary constant.  You can absorb the $\ln 7$ in to the arbitrary constant.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. I thought it was something to do with ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b) but I couldn't make the connection. Thank you.